# R: Recursively specify the input to a function basis the output of the last invocation

Tags: r, recursion, functional-programming

I am looking to choose a sequence of random samples from a bounded range [a, b] where `b` is recursively replaced by the value drawn in the previous sampling.

So, say I draw 0.07 from [0.01, 0.1] in the first round, then I would like to draw from [0.01, 0.07] in the next round. If now I draw 0.033, then I would like the next draw to be in the range [0.01, 0.33]. Assume for simplicity that I want the random draws to be uniformly distributed in each iteration.

The parameter should the number of draws to be made, so 10, 100, 1000, etc.  What is the most efficient way to do this? Ideally using some functional programming niceties.

---

### Edit:

Here is a function that closely follows the Fibonacci recursion example:

```
get_rand_1 = function(n, lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1) {
  if(n == 1) return(runif(1, lower, upper))
  return(runif(1, 0.01, get_rand_1(n-1, lower, upper)))
}

set.seed(1234567)
sapply(1:10, get_rand_1)
```

This does do what I need it to do, but it does produce `NaN`s from time to time, as in this output:

```
> sapply(1:10, get_rand_1)
 [1] 0.05666382 0.06759059        NaN 0.01245241 0.01019525 0.01117497 0.01096470 0.01001802
 [9] 0.01005574 0.01001110
Warning messages:
1: In runif(1, 0.01, get_rand_1(n - 1, lower, upper)) : NAs produced
2: In runif(1, 0.01, get_rand_1(n - 1, lower, upper)) : NAs produced
```

I am not sure whether this is an artifact of the seed, or whether this is an inherent flaw of the program or both.

Specifically, if I hardcode the upper and lower limits and do not pass them as arguments, this does not happen.

```
get_rand = function(n) {
  if(n == 1) return(runif(1, 0.001, 0.1))
  return(runif(1, 0.001, get_rand(n-1)))
}
set.seed(1234567)
sapply(1:10, get_rand)
```

This produces:

```
> set.seed(1234567)
> sapply(1:10, get_rand)
 [1] 0.056663823 0.066827837 0.002083137 0.004200264 0.001238414 0.003118070 0.001038515 0.001121686
 [9] 0.001084810 0.001020310
```

This is on a Windows 10 machine. I can provide session info as required.

In either case, I am still looking to implement this in the most efficient way possible. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic way to do it. Almost certainly not the most efficient, but it will work. Note that it tends to converge to the lower bound because the random number chosen will never be greater than the previous number. The runif(...) function samples from the uniform distribution.

```
 your_sampler <- function(x, a, b){
  temp_list <- c()
  temp_list[1] <- runif(1, min = a, max = b)
  for(i in 2:x){
  temp_list[i] <- runif(1, min = a, max = temp_list[i-1])
  }
  temp_list
}

# Example
your_sampler(10, 0.3, 10)
```